# Trying to Integrate Genius Scan SDK for capturing only the document from camera in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying Integrate Genius scan sdk for capturing only the document from camera in Xamarin.Forms.

One the first step we were facing issue because of the multiple Android Archive (.AAR) files provided by Genius Scan SDK,becuase in Xamarin forms allows us to refer only on Android Archive (.AAR) files.So we were facing issues in binding libraries.

So my question here is how we can do this in Xamarin forms?

So thought of achiving the same in native Xamarin Android project.On that note we converted three Android Archive (.AAR) files into one Android Archive (.AAR) and refered that to Xamarin Android project and while compiling we got error and learnt some of the constraint design and layout file which are for Java are not there in Xamarin Android.So we tried to refer constraint layout from Nuget packages.Once this reference has been made compilation was successfull.
Once after that when we tried to debug the application we are getting issue in ScanConfiguration class file which is in a Com.Thegrizzlylabs.Geniusscan.Sdk.UI.dll and this is present in .AAr file.

Then We changed the package name in AAR file from “Com.Thegrizzlylabs.Geniusscan.Sdk” to “Com.Thegrizzlylabs.Geniusscan.Sdk.UI" which solved the issue.
Now we can able to scan the document while using camera.